# QList of user templated defined structs

Tags: c++, qt, templates, struct, qlist

Can I define a QList such that it holds a collection of templated structs, with each struct defined on different type ??

Consider:

```
template<typename T>struct AA
{
  T value;
}
```

Can I declare a QList such that it holds different instances of AA ??
something like:

```
struct<int> myIntStruct;
myIntStruct.value = 10;
struct<double> myDobleStruct;
myDoubleStruct = 12.2;

template<typename T>
QList<struct AA<T>> myList;
myList.push_back(myIntStruct);
myList.push_back(myDoubleStruct);
```

My Opinion is that the QList should contain entities of same datatype (even for a templated objects) and that's why the above operation is illegal. In that case what structure can I use in Qt to do an operation like that ??

Thanks,

Vishnu.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve here?

Comment: Serializing JSON into easy to use C++ constructs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you would want a container to have dissimilar objects is probably a design flaw.  However some languages support this such as Smalltalk which has the concept of a Bag Collection that can contain a mix of different object types.  Qt may have some sort of bag container class already but I am unaware of it's existence.

This concept of mixed types in a single container does not work so well in the strongly typed world of C++.  Variant objects are the closest thing and even then not for non integral types without making your own "super variant" class which you could do by subclassing `QVariant` then adding some bits to handle your structs.

Again ask yourself the question why do you need this functionality?  A simpler solution implemented elsewhere will probably alleviate the need for such a container.

Edit: Quickie example of `QMap<QString, QVariant>` to help determine if that would work.

```
class SomeObject
{
public:
    SomeObject() // default
        : someInt(0), someDouble(0) {}
    SomeObject(int i, double d) // explicit
        : someInt(i), someDouble(d) {}

    int GetSomeInt() const { return someInt; }
    double GetSomeDouble() const { return someDouble; }

private:
    int someInt;
    double someDouble;
};

// must be outside of namespace
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SomeObject)

// then you can do stuff like this:
    QMap<QString, QVariant> mapNameToValue;

    // populate map
    mapNameToValue["UserName"] = "User";
    mapNameToValue["Port"] = 10101;
    mapNameToValue["PI"] = 3.14159265;
    mapNameToValue["DateTime"] = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    QVariant userValue;
    userValue.setValue(SomeObject(5, 34.7));
    mapNameToValue["SomeObject"] = userValue;

    // read from map
    QString userName = mapNameToValue["UserName"].toString();
    unsigned int port = mapNameToValue["Port"].toUInt();
    double PI = mapNameToValue["PI"].toDouble();
    QDateTime date = mapNameToValue["DateTime"].toDateTime();
    SomeObject myObj = mapNameToValue["SomeObject"].value<SomeObject>();

    int someInt = myObj.GetSomeInt();
    double someDouble = myObj.GetSomeDouble();
```

`QVariant` handles a lot of types it also has template methods `setValue` and `value<>` for user defined types.  As shown briefly above you have to use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` macro to register it with `QMetaType` and provide a default constructor in case `value<>` conversion fails.  It won't support certain comparison operators so I would make my own version of `QVariant` and `QMetaType` to play nice with any extra types needed so it feels more consistent.

Comment: In my code, I want to have a framework that reads JSON files into very simple, easy to use structs. In JSON, one cannot predict the type of the next name/value pair that is to be read, thus generating a requirement for multiple types in a single array or struct.

Comment: Ah so you don't want to define a struct that has each type as that would be wasteful. If it's always a key/value pair perhaps `QMap<QString, QVariant>` would work for you.  If you have multiple values for the same key then you'd use `QMultiMap` instead.

Answer (score 1):

A template class isn't a class, it's a *template*. You can use it to instantiate *completely unrelated classes*, such as `AA<int>` and `AA<double>`.

In order to get the functionality you're looking for - adding unrelated classes to a container - you need either a container that specifically supports adding such unrelated instances, or you need to wrap your objects in e.g. `boost::variant`

Comment: I do not think i can use boost in my project, Is there any such wrapper in Qt??

Comment: `QVariant` will do for types like `int` or `double`

Comment: You can use boost in QT ... but you shouldn't need to as QT has quite a lot of similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you can't generally have non-homogeneous types in the same container.

You can get around that with containers of (smart) pointers, `boost::any`, `boost::variant`, and I'm sure other mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `MyTemplateClass<int>` and `MyTemplateClass<double>` are considered to be separate data types, so you can't have a QList containing both types at once.

You've got options, though.  If you're just storing simple data types, check out [QVariant](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qvariant.html).  It's a single class type, but it uses unions to hold a variety of data types inside it.  And it's built-in, since you're already using Qt!

If you're trying to store more complicated things, polymorphic classes are probably the way to go.  Then you can have a QList of `MyBaseType*`s, and have all the functions you need to call from the list be `virtual`.  You can even make MyBaseType inherit from QVariant, so the data storage is taken care of for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can QVariant store a non-QObject ? i.e can it store struct instances like the ones i have used above (i.e myIntStruct and myDoubleStruct)??

Comment: [It seems that it can.](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qvariant.html#fromValue)  I've never used this myself, but it looks fairly straightforward.  You need to have a few default constructors on your classes, and you need to use [this macro](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)...  But as I said, I'm not familiar with the details - good luck!